# Simple recaptcha doesn't work on VPS server, but works on another hosting server

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have the following codes in 2 websites. Recaptcha works fine on normal hosting but doesn't work on VPS server.
Its really strange.
I crossed checked like 1000 times.

FYI, I got SSL Installed as well. Recaptcha v2.
The response['success'] on VPS is always false

index.php

```
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<form action="test.php" method="post">

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***"></div>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">              

</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => '***',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
    } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
        echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
    }

    ?>
```

I have used the different secret code for each websites. Is there a problem with Godaddy VPS? Or my code?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190775/discussion-on-question-by-webgen-simple-recaptcha-doesnt-work-on-vps-server-bu). If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] the question to include it, rather than posting in comments.

Comment: OMG finally by going to WHM-> Software->Multi php ini -> Could change. works fine now. thank you all